# Implementation of unix terminal background process.

Tags: background-process, shellexecute

I'm writing my own shell in c, and problem is in implementation of background process.
Now on BASH whenever we execute a process ending with '&' then that process goes in background
and start executing, Output of background process comes on terminal and when **background process needs input then it is suspended** until we give "fg" command.

So how to implement background process?

For any normal execution of commands (not ending with &) I call fork system call, and then in child process I execute the command, parent will wait for execution of child process(by wait()).

And for commands having '&' I done same thing but parent will not wait for execution of child process. Here my problem is **whenever background process needs input it take control over terminal**. so how to suspend child process when it needs input.

Comment: Have you taken a look at the bash source code? http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/bash/

Answer (score 0):

To detach the process from the parent, you need to use setsid() on the children process, it will run the program in new session

```
 sid = setsid();
```

See also http://www.netzmafia.de/skripten/unix/linux-daemon-howto.html

Comment: setsid is use for create a new session. This involve three steps  
(a) becomes a session leader of a new session,
(b) becomes the process group leader of a new process group,
(c) has no controlling terminal

But when i execute command "fg", background process takes control on terminal. So now if I use setsid(), the problem will be how can a process can be attached to another process.